# Use CancelAfter on CancellationTokenSource with loop

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

I want create a class helper that implement a timeout.
Because a task it cannot be stopped once started i use a loop.
I want use this pattern without pass CancellationToken on GetAsync.
My question is : this code is it the best you can use or can the cycle cause performance problems ?
To understand sample : if you change https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3 ( with delay=4) you don't have timeout.
Another important question if  CancelAfter is not raised why my code still to run ( see output )?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RetryDemo {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Example();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void Example() {
            Stopwatch Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(((AggregateException)e.ExceptionObject).InnerExceptions.Single().Message); };
                var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = source.Token;

                var task = Task.Run(async () => {
                    try {
                        using (token.Register(() => {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Timeout elapsed {Stopwatch.Elapsed}");
                        })) {
                            Task<HttpResponseMessage> message = GetPage("https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=4");
                            while (true) {
                                if (!token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                                    if (message.IsCompleted) {
                                        HttpResponseMessage messageSync = await message;
                                        Console.WriteLine(await messageSync.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                                Thread.Sleep(200);
                                Console.Write(".");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                });

                source.CancelAfter(3500);


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPage(string url) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Calling page{url}");
            HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
            return await httpclient.GetAsync(url);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I want use this pattern without pass CancellationToken on GetAsync."_ might I ask why?

Comment: GetAsync is an example of use, my intent is to use a helper task with a maximum execution time

Comment: What helper task? How will you implement the maximum execution time? Please try to be complete in your question, so we can help you best

Answer (score 0):

> I want use this pattern without pass CancellationToken on GetAsync.

Bear in mind that cancellation is cooperative, so this will just end up cancelling the *wait* rather than the operation itself.

> is it the best you can use or can the cycle cause performance problems?

A fully proper solution is rather tricky, since it's easy to forget to dispose everything at the right time. I recommend using [`TaskExtensions.WaitAsync(CancellationToken)`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs) from my [AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/). It does not use polling; instead, it [uses `Register`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/CancellationTokenTaskSource.cs#L29) to cancel the wait immediately on timeout.